# Skip a Job in the Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline which has 10 Jobs configured to run one after the other in the post build action. 
Anytime there's a change in Job's related git code, the build is triggered and all the following jobs run though rest of the Job code were not committed.

For e.g, in a series of 10 jobs in the pipeline, if there's a code change in 2nd job but not in 3rd job then I would like to skip the 2nd job and build the 3rd job directly. 
Likewise, any job where the code is not changed, would like to skip and jump to following job.

Please help me if there;s a way to resolve this unwanted builds in the pipeline.

Thanks in advance

I tried using scm skip and ci skip plugins.

Config change

I need to skip the build in the jenkins pipeline for the jobs that don't need to be built (if there are no code changes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to skip a stage that execute the build, and the job will not be called

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils

if (noChanges)
 { 
    Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(STAGE_NAME)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can jump over a stage by using a *when* Block. Example:

First Job:

```
stage{
     // build steps
}
post {
    build "job2"
}
```

Second Job:

```
stage{
    when{
        expression{ 
            changes_made != true // changes_made parameter should be set according to code changes
        }
    }
    steps{
         // build steps
    }
}
post {
     build "job3"
}
```

In this way you will skip the stages of the second job according to the fact if any code was changed.